# How to count date difference excluding weekend and holidays in Computed Field

Tags: datetime, entities

How to count date difference excluding weekend and holidays?

I should count the number of days between two dates but the weekends and holidays must be excluded from the counting. I used [Computed Field](https://drupal.org/project/computed_field).

```
$start_date_value = array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_date_from'));

$end_date_value = array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_date_to'));

$start_date = new DateObject($start_date_value['value'], '');

$end_date = new DateObject($end_date_value['value'], '');

$entity_field[0]['value'] =$start_date->difference($end_date, 'days');
```

Here is my working code for counting the days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why would you try something like this,

create a variable array that contain all the Hollidays

```
$currentyear=the current year;
$holiday['01-01-'.$currentyear,other holiday,other holiday];

$result=$start_date->difference($end_date, 'days');
for(ctr=0;ctr=sizeof(holiday);ctr++;)
{
    if(holiday[ctr]>=start_date && holiday[ctr]<=end_date)
    temp++;

} 
$result -= temp;
```

Comment: Thanks @junnel. I'll try it.

But the code is for holidays only. Can you also help me to exclude the weekends in the counting?

Comment: by that i woudl now suggest to create first a function to count the weekdays base on your from_date to end_date befor you go to holliday exclusion

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find this answer helpful, though it's PHP only:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336127/calculate-business-days/19221403#19221403

So you should only need to input your `$start_date/$end_date` values in correct format and then also define the holidays.